# get content from resultset into array php

Tags: php, arrays, resultset

I have an resultset from mysql Query With query like `SELECT DISTINCT c.id as course_id, c.fullname as fullname, c.shortname as shortname`, it returns as `$return[]`, what i want to do is grab an `c.id` from this result set and store it in array. I have

```
foreach($returnSet as $rs)
{
    $i = 0;
    $courses=array($course->course_id[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Is this the right way to do it, or I am on the wrong path, any guidelines someone?)

Comment: test it and debug it...google a little.if still unclear..Stack is the right place for u then

Comment: define array outside foreach and inside foreach use something like array_push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
$courses = array();
if (!empty($returnSet)) { //check if the $returnSet has anything inside it
   foreach($returnSet as $rs) {
      $courses[] = isset($rs->course_id) ? $rs->course_id : '';
   }
}

print_r($courses);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be as below

```
$cources = array();
foreach($returnSet as $rs)
{
     $courses[] = $rs->course_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I have understood your question correctly, but I think the answer is:

```
$array = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT c.id as course_id, c.fullname as fullname, c.shortname as shortname") or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $array[] = $data["course_id"];
}

print_r($array); #=> array(1, 2, 3, 4...)
```